# Organize an HTML table by item ID

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

I have an HTML table that pulls in data that is stored locally. It searches through the model in the foreach loop and then displays the information in two columns (Patient Name & SiteID). Is there a way that I can display the information so that it is organized by SiteID?

```
<table id="patient_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Site ID</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@string.Format("{0} {1}", item.FirstName, item.LastName)</td>
            <td class="TableAlign">@Html.ActionLink(string.Format("{0}", item.SiteId), "Details", "Site", new { id = item.SiteId }, null)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has `knockout.js` tagged. However, your example code is using ASP.NET and Razor to iterate through your Model.

Based on what you have presented, if your Model is `IEnumerable` I would alter your `@foreach` like so, which should order the displayed information by SiteId:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.SiteId))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that :)

```
this.allItems(this.allItems().sort(function(a, b) { return a.SiteId > b.SiteId ;}));
```